# Extract specific data from pdf using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a pdf file from which I have to extract information such as ID (six-digit number), company name, property address (from `:` upto taxes owed), taxes owed (in dollars), legal description (starting with `Ward` upto next ID) from each para of the pdf but when I am reading text from pdf using PyPdf2 module every para of the file is coming in a single string.

This is my code:

```
import pypdf2, re
pdfObj = open(r'D:\FreeLancing\tax_2019 - PDF to extract the information from.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfObj)
pdfReader.numPages
pdfPageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
text = pdfPageObj.extractText()
re.sub(r'\s\n|\s\n.*|\n', ' ', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
re.split(r'^\d{6}.*\d{6}$', text, flags=re.I | re.DOTALL)
```

from this code I am getting this
[output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueVIE.png)

So I have to ask you that If you can guide me how can I extract the data required using regex from the long output screen. or If possible can u tell me how can I split the text extracted from pdf into para as they are in pdf file.

[This is the pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nq5aI5jrcM8yDJb6LcdCuQdkAEp5gWsi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Remark: careful extracting with PyPDF2, from the doc "Locate all text drawing commands, in the order they are provided in the content stream, and extract the text. **This works well for some PDF files, but poorly for others**, depending on the generator used. This will be refined in the future. Do not rely on the order of text coming out of this function, as it will change if this function is made more sophisticated." this is fix in PyPDF4 (same syntax as PyPDF2)

Comment: what is the output of your regex?

Comment: I have given the output screenshot in the question

Comment: Please __provide the string__ inside `text` (as seen on image)  as code snippet to the question. Then we can test our regular-expressions. Even better would be, if you could upload a sample PDF-page somewhere (GitHub?), at least a screenshot. I suppose extraction can be improved: desired information could be mapped by layout-structure instead of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"^\s*\d{6}\b\s+(?P<id>.*?)\s*PROPERTY\sADDRESS\s*:\s*(?P<address>.*?)\s*TAXES\sOWED\sARE\s+(?P<taxes_owed>.*?)\s*(?P<legal_description>Ward.*?)\.\s*$")
for company_info in re.split(r'(?<=\.)\s*(?=\d{6}\b)', text) :
    src = pattern.search(company_info)
    for group_name in ["id", "address", "taxes_owed", "legal_description"] :
    print(src.group(group_name))
```

See https://regex101.com/r/OtHH5l/1 for the regex explanation.